# How to map .NET function call to property automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

**Edit: This was originally for 1:1 mapping, but I figured out that I needed a more complicated recursive mapping so a new question was posted here: [How to recursively map entity to view model with Automapper function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573600/how-to-recursively-map-entity-to-view-model-with-automapper-function-call)**

I am trying to generically map an entity class function to a view model, using ServiceStack ConvertTo<> method. This maps all similar types and property names and works fine, but I want to find a way to map the result of a function to a property. Here is some code

Entity example:

```
public class Item {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public List<Product> GetProducts() {
          return Repository.GetAll<Product>();
    }
}
```

ViewModel example:

```
 public class ItemViewModel {
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
 }
```

The ideal result would be to have a map function that looks at the entity class for a method that matches the return type and the function name is "Get" + Property name, then to execute it and map the result to the view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might be able to find that something like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) or [Value Injecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) could already contain this functionality, there's nothing from stopping you from writing a quick little utility method:

```
public TTarget MapToViewModel<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source)
    where TTarget : new()
{
    var sourceType = source.GetType();

    var targetProperties = typeof(TTarget).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var sourceProperties = sourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var sourceMethods = sourceType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    var target = Activator.CreateInstance<TTarget>();

    foreach (var prop in targetProperties)
    {
        var sourceProp = sourceProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == prop.Name);
        if (sourceProp != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(target, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
        }
        else
        {
            var sourceMethod = sourceMethods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Get" + prop.Name);
            if (sourceMethod != null)
            {
                prop.SetValue(target, sourceMethod.Invoke(source, null), null);
            }
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```

The conditions in the `.FirstOrDefault` calls above just use `Name`, but you could expand them to whatever you like.

To use this, just call it like so:

```
var itemViewModel = MapToViewModel<Item, ItemViewModel>(item);
```

Just be careful if you have any parameters for your methods in your regular model. If you find that your models are too complex (or don't follow one or two naming conventions), then you might be better off with something like AutoMapper. For simple mappings, though, something like this should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working. Now I have another dilemma. How difficult would it be to make this recursive? For example, if the Product class had a property List<Image> Images and I needed to call GetImages() from the Product class?

Comment: I'm not really seeing how that would require a recursive call. Do you mean that if both a method and a property exist on an object, then the method needs called instead? If that's the case, you could switch `if` statements for properties and methods to check for methods first.

Comment: Not exactly, I mean if the mapped object had another property that needed to be mapped by calling a different function. Your answer helped me determine I needed something a little more complicated, which it seems like Automapper may be able to handle. I asked another Q here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573600/how-to-recursively-map-entity-to-view-model-with-automapper-function-call

Comment: Yep, with AutoMapper, you could set up maps for multiple objects, and send it on its way. For example, you could call `Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>()` and `Mapper.CreateMap<Image, ImageViewModel>()`. Then, when you call `Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel>(product)`, it *should* return what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this mapping with ServiceStack would be quite difficult to make a general solution, as you'd basically have to write the code to match `Products` to `GetProducts` yourself.

You could use another mapping library, like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), which automatically uses `GetX()` to populate `X`.

```
// one time config
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

// whenever you map
Item item = // whatever
ItemViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<ItemViewModel>(item);
// viewModel.Products is populated from item.GetProducts()
```

It's also much easier to manually change how certain things are mapped, e.g. you could manually set this one using this `CreateMap`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Products,
                      opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.GetProducts()));
```

It looks like AutoMapper is a much more robust mapper. Even if you use ServiceStack for other portions, it may be worth it to use AutoMapper for your mapping.

Comment: Nice, I figured AutoMapper could do something like this (even if it was just using the `.AfterMap` funciton)

Comment: Nice, I did not consider Automapper. Would Automapper support this recursively?

Comment: Yes (I think; not sure what you mean by "recursively"), e.g. if `Products` and `GetProducts` returned different types, but there was a map created between those two product types, (e.g. `Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>();`) it will map those items automatically as well.

Comment: Added a spin-off question because I think Automapper is going to be able to do what I want easier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573600/how-to-recursively-map-entity-to-view-model-with-automapper-function-call